# Combining two arrays by ID in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to compare two 2D arrays in PHP. The arrays look like this:

```
Array one
ID Name
11 Aa 
11 Ab
12 Bb
13 Cc
14 Dd
15 Ee

Array two
ID Content
11 Cat
13 Dog
14 Donkey
```

Now I'd need to combine these two into an array like this:

```
ID Name Conent
11 Aa Cat
11 Ab Cat
12 Bb
13 Cc Dog
14 Dd Donkey
15 Ee
```

How can I accomplish this? I have had no luck with array_merge() or $array3 = $array1 + $array2;

Comment: Are you just trying to concatenate the two string with same ID's into a single string, or are you trying to have in essence one key with multiple values?

Comment: array_merge/addition don't change the dimensionality of the arrays. If you feed in two 1x10 arrays, you end up with 1x20, not 2x10 or 4x5 or whatever.

Comment: I finally solved this by altering the SQL query. Seems like php is not very suitable for working on complex arrays. :-(

Answer (score 5):

A quick way would be to iterate over the first array and append the value from the second:

```
$array1 = array('11' => 'Aa', '12' => 'Bb', '13' => 'Cc', '14' => 'Dd', '15' => 'Ee');
$array2 = array('11' => 'Cat', '13' => 'Dog', '14' => 'Donkey');

$combined = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
    $combined[$key] = $val . (isset($array2[$key]) ? ' '.$array2[$key] : '');
}
```

This will loop through every key/value in `$array1` and add it to the `$combined` array. If a value in `$array2` exists with the same index, it will append it to that value from `$array1`, separated with a space.

**UPDATE:** I misread the format of the arrays (again). I assumed `ID` was the actual index in the array, but as the example array output has both `Name` and `Content`, I'm assuming `ID` is an actual index string value and not the index in the array itself. To stick with the loop scenario, you can iterate through the first array and have a nested loop iterate through the second:

```
$array1 = array(
        array('ID' => '11', 'Name' => 'Aa'),
        array('ID' => '12', 'Name' => 'Bb'),
        array('ID' => '13', 'Name' => 'Cc'),
        array('ID' => '14', 'Name' => 'Dd'),
        array('ID' => '15', 'Name' => 'Ee'),
    );
$array2 = array(
        array('ID' => '11', 'Content' => 'Cat'),
        array('ID' => '13', 'Content' => 'Dog'),
        array('ID' => '14', 'Content' => 'Donkey')
    );

$combined = array();
foreach ($array1 as $arr) {
        $comb = array('ID' => $arr['ID'], 'Name' => $arr['Name'], 'Content' => '');
        foreach ($array2 as $arr2) {
            if ($arr2['ID'] == $arr['ID']) {
                $comb['Content'] = $arr2['Content'];
                break;
            }
        }
    $combined[] = $comb;
}
```

This will add every value in `$array1` to the combined array and if, and only if, a value in `$array2` contains the same `ID` field will it add it's `Content` field to the array too. This can be extended to handle any number of fields as well, either by name, or by changing the inner-if block to have `$comb += $arr2;` instead (which should merge all non-existing indexes).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make your own function:

```
function putThemTogether($array1, $array2) {
    $output = array();
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($output[$key]))
            $output[$key] = array();
        $output[$key][] = $value;
    }
    foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($output[$key]))
            $output[$key] = array();
        $output[$key][] = $value;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

To make this better you could make it take an arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_map (
  function ($item) { return is_array($item) ? implode(' ', $item) : $item; },
  array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
);
```

Note, that both arrays require string keys

Answer (score 0):

**Try this I hope It'll work**

```
function merge_two_arrays($array1,$array2) {
    $data = array();
    $arrayAB = array_merge($array1,$array2);
    foreach ($arrayAB as $value) {
        // This assumes there is a field called "id"
        $id = $value['id'];
        if (!isset($data[$id])) {
            $data[$id] = array();
        }
        $data[$id] = array_merge($data[$id],$value);
    }
    return $data;
}

$master_array = merge_two_arrays($array1,$array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this is to use `array_search` and `array_column` (since PHP 5.5.0).

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $val) {
    $found_key = array_search($val['ID'], array_column($array2, 'ID'));
    if ($found_key !== false) { $array1[$key]['Content'] = $array2[$found_key]['Content']; }
}
```