# Add attribute from secondary array to primary array in php

Tags: php, laravel

i have tow arrays the primary array is  $allcustomers wich seems to be as follow

```
    array:4 [▼
  0 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "name" => "shahd"
    "gender" => "F"
    "helper_code" => null
    "age" => 255.0
    "dob" => 1768.0
    "mobile_no" => "01789654123"
    "category" => null
    "status" => 0
    "created_by" => 8
    "updated_by" => null
    "created_at" => "2023-08-14T18:56:26.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => null
  ]
  1 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "amr"
    "gender" => "M"
    "helper_code" => 252
    "age" => 25.0
    "dob" => 1998.0
    "mobile_no" => "01252523987"
    "category" => "Mixed"
    "status" => 47
    "created_by" => 8
    "updated_by" => 8
    "created_at" => "2023-08-10T08:05:00.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-08-10T19:35:00.000000Z"
  ]
  2 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "mohamed shaker"
    "gender" => "M"
    "helper_code" => 2525
    "age" => 2.0
    "dob" => 2021.0
    "mobile_no" => "01999999999"
    "category" => "Mixed"
    "status" => 9
    "created_by" => 8
    "updated_by" => 8
    "created_at" => "2023-08-01T09:51:51.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-08-10T10:57:43.000000Z"
  ]
  3 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "tasnim"
    "gender" => "F"
    "helper_code" => 255
    "age" => 25.0
    "dob" => 1998.0
    "mobile_no" => "01252525256"
    "category" => null
    "status" => 0
    "created_by" => 8
    "updated_by" => null
    "created_at" => "2023-07-11T19:13:55.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => null
  ]
]
```

the secondary one is $lastvisitdate seems to be as follow

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "date" => "2023-08-28"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "date" => "2023-08-10"
  ]
]
```

i need to add date from secondary array to primary to be as follow consider id matching and if id not exist in secondary array it added with null value in the primary array

```
    array:4 [▼
  0 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "name" => "shahd"
    "gender" => "F"
    "helper_code" => null
    "age" => 255.0
    "dob" => 1768.0
    "mobile_no" => "01789654123"
    "category" => null
    "status" => 0
    "created_by" => 8
    "updated_by" => null
    "created_at" => "2023-08-14T18:56:26.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => null
    "date" => null
  ]
  1 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "amr"
    "gender" => "M"
    "helper_code" => 252
    "age" => 25.0
    "dob" => 1998.0
    "mobile_no" => "01252523987"
    "category" => "Mixed"
    "status" => 47
    "created_by" => 8
    "updated_by" => 8
    "created_at" => "2023-08-10T08:05:00.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-08-10T19:35:00.000000Z"
     "date" => "2023-08-10"
  ]
  2 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "mohamed shaker"
    "gender" => "M"
    "helper_code" => 2525
    "age" => 2.0
    "dob" => 2021.0
    "mobile_no" => "01999999999"
    "category" => "Mixed"
    "status" => 9
    "created_by" => 8
    "updated_by" => 8
    "created_at" => "2023-08-01T09:51:51.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-08-10T10:57:43.000000Z"
    "date" => "2023-08-28"
  ]
  3 => array:13 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "tasnim"
    "gender" => "F"
    "helper_code" => 255
    "age" => 25.0
    "dob" => 1998.0
    "mobile_no" => "01252525256"
    "category" => null
    "status" => 0
    "created_by" => 8
    "updated_by" => null
    "created_at" => "2023-07-11T19:13:55.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => null
    "date" => null
  ]
]
```

Comment: This is more on PHP rather than laravel. Use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11633969/13933721

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use join in your query? instead of multiple foreach in your php code.
you tagged laravel, so let's see the joining query in laravel
laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#joins

```
$allcustomers = DB::table('customers')
            ->join('last_visit', 'customers.id', '=', 'last_visit.id')
            ->select('customers.*', 'last_visit.date')
            ->get();
```

you can also define the relationships in their model for easier access; read here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: thanks here is my laravel query 
      `$allcustomers=Customer::latest()->get()->toArray();
        $lastvisitdate = bookingdt::orderby('date','desc')
        ->selectRaw('customer_id as id,max(date) as date')
        ->groupBy('customer_id')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();`